# Conversion of specific format of xml to dataframe

Tags: python, xml

I have a file coming in this format where I need to calculate financial ratios and use them for rule verification using pyke. I thought will use Pandasql for calculating ratios in one single go and return the ratios to Pyke. Facing issues in parsing data and conversion to a dataframe.

Here is the sample file. ( Ruleid - unique rule to be applied , CIN -Company identification Number. The third column contains values for which ratio needs to be calculated. Thank you :)

```js
<Records>
  <Record>
    <Row name="Ruleid" value="1" />
     <row name="CIN" value="A" />
     <row name="Sales" value ="1400" />
     <row name="Year" value="2000" />
     />
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <Row name="Ruleid" value="1" />
     <row name="CIN" value="A" />
     <row name="Inventory" value ="1300" />
     <row name="Year" value="1999" />
     />
      </Record>
   <Record>
    <Row name="Ruleid" value="1" />
     <row name="CIN" value="A" />
     <row name="Sales" value ="1100" />
     <row name="Year" value="1998" />
     />
  </Record>
     <Record>
    <Row name="Ruleid" value="1" />
     <row name="CIN" value="A" />
     <row name="Inventory" value ="2000" />
     <row name="Year" value="1997" />
     />
  </Record>
  </Records>
```

Comment: Please wrote what is your question?

Comment: I need to calculate financial ratios . Facing issues in parsing and converting to dataframe.  Saw couple of examples but none seem to work for this case of pattern of xml. Could any body provide a sample pseudo code in Python to execute the code